# CiviCRM Wordpress Installer Database Instructions incorrect?

Tags: database

Instructions were here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/

I downloaded the zip to my local computer, then ftp uploaded it to my web server. I created the /wp-content/plugins/files/ directory and ensured it is writable.

I'm not using Localization so I skipped that section.

I then enabled the CiviCRM plugin and ran the installer. I filled in the database settings, and it continued on with the Check Requirements and Install CiviCRM which completed successfully.

The part I don't understand is that the installer assigns a database administrator name and password, however the password is starred out ***** so I do not know what it is. I don't get the point of this, how can I possibly maintain or recover the database if I don't have the password credentials???

I thought that after the install it would email me those credentials but it appears to be top secret so that even me, the administrator, cannot know it. How do I obtain this password?

Answer (score 1):

This is the MySQL password and not the WordPress administrator password.  If you used the same MySQL database for WordPress and CiviCRM, check `wp-config.php` in the root of your WordPress installation to find the password.

If you used separate databases (or you're not sure), find `civicrm.settings.php`.  On a new install, this should be in `<webroot>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm`.  Open it in a text editor and look for a line that looks like:

```
define('CIVICRM_DSN', 'mysql://<mysql_user>:<mysql_password>@127.0.0.1:3306/<mysql_database>?new_link=true');
```

The password should be everything after the second colon and before the @ sign.

**Note:** there's a very similar-looking like that starts with:
`define( 'CIVICRM_UF_DSN'`.  This contains your WordPress connection info and not your CiviCRM connection info.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Jenni and Jon. Both of you referred to a singular database/password. Perhaps this is where my confusion comes from: I'm assuming Civi created a completely new and separate database from my Wordpress database (which I do know the password to). So, to clarify, are you saying that the Civi data is in the Wordpress database that was already there?

Comment: @JP6805 I'm sorry - I made some assumptions about how you installed.  You can install CiviCRM data into its own database, or into the WordPress database.  I'll edit my answer above to give a more definitive answer.

Comment: That said - I know that the WordPress installer recently got overhauled to auto-fill this info, it used to be you defined it yourself.  It sounds like maybe we need a fresh set of eyes to see if there's a usability issue now.

Comment: Installer was for 4.7.27 and it auto-filled that password field, just to confirm for you. I have no idea what database it installed to, as it did not give me an option.

Comment: Yes thanks for that, I see now that Civi used the same database as WP.

Answer (score 0):

The database admin should be the one for your actual database - which is created in your hosting account. Unless the WP install is *very* different from Drupal, the database admin information that goes in my installer is what is assigned in my control panel for the database in question.